# Problema condicionales PHP

Tags: php, condiciones, sesiones

Hola tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php 
  
  /if (isset($_SESSION["Ingresar"]) && $_SESSION["Ingresar"] == true) {/


    //echo '<div class="wrapper">';

  include "modulos/cabecera.php";

  include "modulos/menu.php";

  //include "modulos/seleccionar.php";

  //echo '</div>';


  $url = array();

  if(isset($_GET["url"])) {

    $url = explode("/", $_GET["url"]);

    if ($url[0] == "inicio") {

      include "modulos/".$url[0].".php";

    } 

  }else {

      include "modulos/inicio.php";
    
    }

    
    echo '</div>';

  } else if (isset($_GET["url"])) {

    if ($_GET["url"] == "seleccionar") {

      include "modulos/seleccionar.php";

    }

  }


  ?>
```

Si se cumplen ciertas condiciones, lo que quiero es que me re direccione a mi pantalla de seleccionar solo que no lo hace, me manda error 404, creo que es problema con mis condicionales o si alguien me pudiera decir como se hace o cual es mi error por favor, esta es mi primera vez haciendo algo así espero si se entienda el código o lo que intento hacer, de antemano muchísimas gracias

Comment: No veo ninguna redirección en tu código. Los errores 404 ocurren cuando intentas ir a una página que no existe. Verifica cómo se crean las rutas, que no haya errores de sintaxis, que son correctas, que  las carpetas/archivos existen realmente.

Comment: Falta incluir al inicio de tu script `session_start()` ya que tal como esta no tiene sentido la primera validación (ya que las variables de sesión no están inicializadas)

Comment: Consulta. Veo que tienes una variable get que evalúas ¿Cual es el formato de tus url?. Aunque es curioso que tengas errores 404, ya que como menciona @A.Cedano no estas redireccionando nada, a lo mas debiesen aparecer algunos warning por los includes.